# Get SeekBar position of MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my Android application i am playing the desired video using default MediaPlayed usin intent.The code for it is as follows

```
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file=new File(sdcard,"big-buck-bunny.m4v");        
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

But now I want to SeekBar position of the playing video.
Please provide me solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, you'll have to adapt for your needs:

```
mp.getDuration();
seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {

    seekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());

    if (mp.isPlaying()) {

        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                startPlayProgressUpdater();
                textViewSongTime1.setText(("Total: ")
                        + (getTimeString(mp.getDuration())));
                textViewSongTime2.setText(("Remaining: ")
                        + (getTimeString(mp.getDuration()
                                - mp.getCurrentPosition())));
            }

        };

        handler.postDelayed(notification, 300);

    } else {

        mp.pause();

        seekBar.setProgress(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you get seekBar from ?

Comment: `public static SeekBar seekBar;` `seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);`